# php: getting random values or multi-values in order from an array

Tags: php, arrays

My array;

```
$array=array("x","y","z","t","k");
```

for example i wanna get 10 results from this array and want this results are in-order(array order) & has random number values.

like this:

1. result: x
2. result: x|y|k
3. result: z|k
4. result: y
5. result: x
6. result: x|y|z|t|k
7. result: y|z|k
8. result: x|t
9. result: k
10. result: x|z

but no result for: z|x or t|y|k (because these are not in array order.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
function get_random_list($arr, $count) {
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $length = mt_rand(1, count($arr));
        $keys = (array)array_rand($arr, $length);
        sort($keys);
        $items = array();
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $items[] = $arr[$key];
        }
        $result[] = $items;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo implode("<br />", array_map(function($arr) {
    return implode("|", $arr);
}, get_random_list($array, 10)));
```

Example outputted value:

```
k<br />x<br />y<br />x|y|z|t|k<br />z<br />y|t|k<br />z<br />y|z<br />z<br />y|k
```

Comment: @OzzyChigurh:  You can [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) the return value of the function to see what was returned.